# Вывод таблицы Foreign key и url detail Django

Tags: django, url, foreign-key

Доброго времени суток. Не могу решить вопрос. Имеются модели:

```
class TbCompany(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(
    max_length=256)

class TbVacancy(models.Model):
company = models.ForeignKey(
    'TbCompany',
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    related_name='companies')
position_of_work = models.CharField(
    max_length=256)

class TbVacancyWorker(models.Model):
vacancy = models.ForeignKey(
    'TbVacancy',
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    related_name='vacancies')
name = models.CharField(
    max_length=256)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^vacancy/list/$', vacancy_list, name = 'vacancy_list'),
url(r'^vacancy/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', vacancy_detail, name = 'vacancy_detail')
```

vacancy_list.html

```
{% for company in companies %}
<P>{{company.name}}</p>
    {% if company.companies.all.count > 0%}
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th><a href="#">№</a></th>
              <th><a href="#">Stanowisko</a></th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {% for i in company.companies.all%}
            <tr>                
              <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
              <td><a href="{% КАКОЙ URL СЮДА ПЕРЕДАТЬ %}">{{i.position_of_work}}</a></td>
           </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      {% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

wiews.py

```
def vacancy_list(request):    
companies = TbCompany.objects.all()
return render(request, 'vacancy/vacancy_test.html', {'companies':companies})
```

Нужно вывести таблицу список таблиц с названиями вакансий. При этом должны быть ссылки на детали вакансии. Спасибо

Comment: А что должно выводить company.companies.all.count? И вообще company.companies в шаблоне? Вы ведь и так передаете queryset TbCompany в companies изначально. Мне кажется, тут неправильная архитектура. ForeignKey к TbCompany в TbVacancy означает много-к-одному: т.е. много вакансий к одной компании

Comment: Я вывожу список компаний с вакансиями в формате: Компания1: список вакансий; Компания2: список вакансий. Это не проблема. Проблема состоит в том чтобы передать в шаблоне url на детали вакансии. То есть по клику на вакансию должны выводится детали вакансии. Направьте, или подскажите куда копать. Спасибо

Comment: Блин, все просто. Нужно было просто поспать:) Проблема решена. Спасибо за оказанную помощь.

P.S. Если кому-то нужно будет, в url нужно передать {% url 'vacancy_detail' i.pk%}